# Use internal class in input parameters of a DataTestMethod

Tags: c#, .net, mstest

I am using DataTestMethod with a custom DataSource attribute and I am facing a problem when I want to use an internal class in the input parameters for the DataTestMethod.

```
[DataTestMethod, CustomDataSource]
public void TestMethod(MyInternalClass param1)
{
    // Do whatever
}
```

I see the following error:

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'MyInternalClass' is less
>   accessible than method 'TestMethod(MyInternalClass)'

Is there a way to solve this?
I am already using the `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute in the project so that the test project can use the internal types.

Comment: Declare your test class as `internal`? But better would be to not have to make your internals visible to the unit test - that implies that you are testing an implementation detail.

Comment: Test class needs to be `public`, otherwise MsTest doesn't detect them as tests.

Comment: Those `internal` classes are not public because my project is a library used by others but they should only have access to what is defined as public. Testing internal classes is not testing implementation details. It's not that I am testing privated methods or something of that sort..

Comment: Well, internal classes are *by definition* an implementation detail. Perhaps you can extract a public interface and pass that to `TestMethod()` instead?

Comment: I already have public interfaces but I need the concrete implementation in the input parameters of the Test Method because those parameters are resolved using AutoFixture (with Automoq customization) and if I don't provide a concrete class, they will be resolved as Mocks, which I don't want.

Comment: It seems that the only chance is a custom DTO in the test project which will get translated into `MyInternalClass` in the test method's body.

Comment: I am with sergi here. internal in this situation means implementation detail to downstream clients, but not  unit tests. Unit tests need access to ensure the service implementation is functional. Why compromise the surface of my API just to uphold some arbitrary principles? I understand where the "don't test implementation details" advice comes from; but these are guidelines not hard and fast rules, like everything in software engineering.